# how to get data from three tables by a join statement in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

In my application i have three tables, **reservation**, **patient** and **sub_unit**, i need to take the **patient_id from reservation table and query the patient table for patient data**,***same time*** i need to take the **sub_unit_id from the reservation table and query the sub_unit name from the sub_unit table**... i need to put all this data in to an one array in the sequence like 
patient_id, sub_unit_name, patient_name, address and pass it to the Codeigniter table class to draw a table.

How can I query three tables in the same time to query out this data? can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select r.patient_id, s.sub_unit_name, p.patient_name, p.address 
from reservation r, sub_unit s, patient p 
where r.patient_id = p.patient_id and r.sub_unit_id = s.sub_unit_id
```

Answer (score 4):

Using code igniter syntax it can be done as follows -

```
$this->db->select('r.patient_id, s.sub_unit_name, p.patient_name, p.address');
$this->db->from('reservation r');
$this->db->join('patient p', 'p.id = r.patient_id');
$this->db->join('sub_unit s', 's.id = r.sub_unit_id');
$query = $this->db->get();


You can check your formed query by -
echo $this->db->_compile_select();exit;
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, this is more familiar to me than the solution i found... !

Answer (score 2):

The [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) syntax is very straightforward in SQL. You are probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT   reservation.patient_id, 
         sub_unit.sub_unit_name, 
         patient.patient_name, 
         patient.address
FROM     reservation
JOIN     patient ON (patient.id = reservation.patient_id)
JOIN     sub_unit ON (sub_unit.id = reservation.sub_unit_id);
```

In MySQL, the default join is an [Inner Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join), which I think is what you're looking for. You may also want to look into [Outer Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) which are also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

it worked guys , i did it like this using Codeigniter active records ,hope you guys can use it too

```
    function get_data(){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM visit,patient,sub_unit WHERE visit.patient_patient_id = patient.patient_id AND visit.sub_unit_sub_unit_id = sub_unit.sub_unit_id';

    $this->db->order_by("reference_number", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

thanx for all your support!

Comment: You're using the very old ANSI-89 join syntax in that query (also called an implicit join), instead of the more popular (and modern) ANSI-92 syntax (also called explicit join). While most modern databases will treat both variants in the same way, it is generally recommended to stay away from the old syntax. It is less understandable, since you add an extra expression in the `WHERE` clause for each join, and it is also much easier to forget a join expression.

Comment: thank you very much for that comment Daniel,,, i will study about that! I'm only familiar with this type, that's why i used it!