# MYSQL query to select from multiple tables, order by date, different table structures

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm making a newsfeed type of thing and I want to select from multiple tables. The two tables I'll focus on for this question are "posts" and "photos".

Here's my query for just posts:

```
mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM posts 
            WHERE toID='$id' AND state='0' 
            ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

My posts table has the following column names:

```
Table: posts

id  toID   fromID   post   state     date
1    1       1      Aloha    0       1
2    1       1      Hello    0       3
```

My photos table has the following:

```
Table: photos

id  userID  photo    state    date
1     1       2       0       2
2     1       6       0       4
```

Expected result:

```
Aloha
2
Hello
6
```

Maybe something like:

```
 SELECT * 
 (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE toID=$id AND state=0) AND
 (SELECT * FROM photos WHERE userID=$id AND state=0)
 ORDER BY date
```

When it selects these from the database it should select from where toID and userID are the same. state should equal 0 for both, (0 means visible) and they should be ordered by date. Also I need to create a new variable to pass to my query, so I can then in my php determine which table the information is coming from. Lastly I would like it to group the photos by date, so let's say a user uploaded 20 photos within a 30 minute period, they will only return one row. I use php time() to store my date.

Comment: There is a solution here that i think will be of help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844655/how-to-get-data-from-three-tables-by-a-join-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all posts and photos together you could use:

```
SELECT po.*, ph.* FROM posts po
LEFT JOIN photos ph
    ON po.toID = ph.userID
WHERE po.state = 0
  AND ph.state = 0
ORDER BY po.id DESC, ph.date DESC
```

Comment: it returns posts, but not the photos.

Comment: @DylanCross: it returns posts and photos for every post(if there are, see `LEFT JOIN`). Are you sure that you copied my query correctly?

Comment: Yes, and maybe my question wasn't clear enough? if I have 2 posts (post1, post2) and 2 photos (photo1, photo5) 4 rows should be returned

Comment: @DylanCross: can you please edit your question posting these two records for every table? I've just tried my query and works fine, so I don't understand what's wrong. Edit your question so we can see what's going on...

Comment: @DylanCross: your expected results aren't clear, really. Why for post id=1 you choose photo id=1 and for post id=2 you choose photo id=2? Photos are both for user with userID=1, so they're to be choosen both for every post. Let me understand...

Comment: both "id" columns are irrelevant, they have nothing to do with the query. They both just happened to have 1 and 2 id.

Comment: @DylanCross: both posts have toID=1 and both photos have userID=1, so both photos are shown for every post. Why are you trying to output just one photo for each post? And which is the rule you're using to choose that photo and not the other for each post? You told in your comment "if I have 2 posts (post1, post2) and 2 photos (photo1, photo5) 4 rows should be returned": well, they are, my query returns exactly four rows!!!